# APE handler Windows equivalent of disabling security per IP# using htaccess?

Tags: windows, .htaccess

I want to turn off basic auth in Windows/IIS 7 that is enforced by the [Helicon APE](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) handler. It should be turned off for local IP#s e.g. 192.168.xxx.

Cross-referencing the [Apache docs](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_security-htaccess-tricks.html#m0-askapache4)  with the [Helicon docs](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_setenvif.htm) this seems viable however the environment variable in the Apache example 'MODSEC_ENABLE=Off' doesn't seem to be supported on Windows.

Is there a Helicon alternative that works?

```
# Apache htaccess sample:
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Addr ^192\.168\..+$ MODSEC_ENABLE=Off
```

Comment: I've also submitted a ticket to Helicon support. Either way, when I get it working, I'll ensure the answer is posted below for future reference, unless somebody else answers first from experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ticket Has Been Updated

Hello,

You recently logged a ticket with a subject of APE handler - Disabling security per IP# with us. This e-mail is to advise you of an update to that ticket.

The following comment was added to ticket [inbox-12956]:

Hello,

Please try to add the following portion of code into the .htaccess with the auth directives:

```
# allow access by hosts rules or after authentication
# the following 4 lines should be added on top of your existing auth directives

Satisfy Any
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1 192.168.0.0/16

#this part should already exist in your file.
AuthType basic
AuthName "private area"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Regards,
Inbox
support@helicontech.com